# How to maintain the same format while reading and writing files in Java?

Tags: java, xml, read-write

I am trying to read a xml file(in.arxml) and copy it into another xml file (out.arxml). When I just read the in.arxml file and display the contents in the workspace the spacing and the format is maintained and is exactly as it is in the file. However when I write this into the out.arxml file the entire ile is printed on a single line. Could somebody please tell me wht is it that I doing wrong?  My code to read and write the file looks like this:

```
 BufferedWriter out;
 BufferedReader in;
 String x =null;
 int lineNumb=0;

 try {

            in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("C:\\New_folder\\in.arxml"));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(""C:\\New_folder\\out.arxml"));
            while (in.readLine()!= null){

                x = in.readLine();
                java.lang.System.out.println(x);
                out.write(x);

                lineNumb++;
            }
            in.close();
       }catch (IOException e){
            java.lang.System.out.println("There was a problem" + e);
        }
```

The in.arxml file looks like :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xxx xmlns="http://xd3.h?.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

And the out.arxml that is written looks like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xxx xmlns="http://xd3.h?.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `out.write(x);`, add the following line:

```
out.newLine();
```

This will add the missing carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the content of a file then use `Stream`s not `Reader`s/`Writer`s.

`Stream`s operate at byte level and there is no interpretation while reading and writing bytes.

`Reader`s/`Writer`s operate at character level and some transformations may occur during reading/writing especially charset encoding and/or end-of-lines.

You also forget to output an end-of-line.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
x = in.readLine()
```

stores the content of a line in variable `x`. This string does not contain any line breaks. If you simply write the content of `x` into a file using

```
out.write(x)
```

you will of course lose all the line-breaks. Try to change it to

```
out.write(x + "\n")
```

By the way: the condition in your while-loop should throw away every second line. Is this intended?

Why are you trying to work with XML files in a line-by-line manner? Using some XML framework would seem more appropriate.

Another remark: your current code looks like a strange re-implementation of "TEE". Are you sure that there is a good reason to re-implement it?

Comment: Thank you for your response! This was just a trial program for me to get familiar with arxml file (reading and writing them). :) thnks again!